# How do I select specific characters inside strings?

Tags: c++, string, character

I'm pretty unfamiliar with string manipulation in C++ and I can't seem to wrap my head around how to select characters in strings. Below is my program so far. Whenever I run it, however, the program crashes and an error showing "Thread 1: EXC_BAD..." shows up (I'm working on Xcode). For some reason, simply using input[0] works if I want to print the first character from the string, but doesn't when I do input[x] in a loop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int num, characterCount;
string currentChar, previousChar;

int main()
{
    cout << "How many lines of input? \n";
    cin >> num;
    for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
    {
        string input;
        cin >> input;
    
        previousChar = input[0];
        currentChar = input[1];
        characterCount = 0;
        int y = 0;
        while (currentChar != "")
        {
            y++;
            if (previousChar == currentChar)
            {
                characterCount++;
            }
            else if (previousChar != currentchar && currentChar != "")
            {
                cout << characterCount << " " << previousChar;
                characterCount = 0;
            }
            else if (currentChar == "")
            {
                cout << characterCount << " " << previousChar;
            }
            previousChar = currentChar;
            currentChar = input[y];
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Btw I know my code's weird, I'm a beginner in C++. If you have any helpful suggestions feel free to comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is:

```
currentChar = input[y];
```

The problem with this line is that `input[y]` might be inaccessible, for instance your `input` is `"Hello"`. With the way you wrote your code, `y` would eventually equals `5`. However, you the last letter `'o'` is `input[4]`. Because of that, when `y=5`, you get an error.

There are couple ways you could fix it. One has already mentioned using `.size()` to make sure, another one has mentioned using iterator:

`for(auto iterator = input.begin();iterator!=input.end();++iterator)`

However, what I want to mention is that you should be declaring your `currentChar` and `previousChar` as `char` type instead of `string` since they would always be single characters. Also, depends on the version of C++ and compiler you are using, if you are using C++11, `input[5]` on `"Hello"` is actually fine.

When you passed `input[5]` to a `char currentChar` type, `currentChar` gets a null character. So for you while loop, you could test `while(currentChar)`. When `currentChar` gets the null character, the while loop would test false, and ends the loop.

Below is how I would change inside your for loop. Most of them stays the same, beside changing `previousChar` and `currentChar` into `char` type, and some condition checkings for them, with some minor changes to refine them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int num;
    std::cout << "How many lines of input? \n";
    std::cin >> num;
    for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
    {
        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;
        
        char previousChar = input[0];
        int y = 1;
        char currentChar = input[y];
        int characterCount = 1;
        while(currentChar)
        {
            y++;
            if (previousChar == currentChar)
            {
                characterCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << characterCount << " " << previousChar << "\n";
                characterCount = 1;
            }
            previousChar = currentChar;
            currentChar = input[y];
        }
        std::cout << characterCount << " " << previousChar << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

Also do note that it feels weird to use a while loop when it is iterating through a index number for me. So I would probably use a for loop instead of the while loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int num;
    std::cout << "How many lines of input? \n";
    std::cin >> num;
    for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
    {
        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;
        
        char previousChar = input[0];
        int y = 1;
        char currentChar = input[y];
        int characterCount = 0;
        for(int y = 1; currentChar; y++)
        {
            if (previousChar == currentChar)
            {
                characterCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << characterCount << " " << previousChar << "\n";
                characterCount = 1;
            }
            previousChar = currentChar;
            currentChar = input[y];
        }
        std::cout << characterCount << " " << previousChar << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

And here is how you could do it with iterator:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    int num;
    std::cout << "How many lines of input? \n";
    std::cin >> num;
    for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
    {
        std::string input;
        std::cin >> input;
        
        char previousChar, currentChar;
        previousChar = input[0];
        int characterCount = 1;
        for(auto it = input.begin()+1; it != input.end();it++)
        {
            currentChar = *it;
            if (previousChar == currentChar)
            {
                characterCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << characterCount << " " << previousChar << "\n";
                characterCount = 1;
            }
            previousChar = currentChar;
        }
        std::cout << characterCount << " " << previousChar << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried both the first and second solutions that you've shown, and neither actually get to cout << characterCount before the program ends. What could the problem be?

Comment: The code I had require c++ 11 or later. And it's possible you are using an older version of c++. You can refer to: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/350627/how-can-i-specify-the-c-version-to-use-with-xcode to change your c++ version

Comment: actually, my version is c++ 17, which I think is the most recent version. Basically, after I enter the input in the program, it immediately ends. I've tried inserting cout << "trigger" in else {}, but it didn't print so I'm assuming that it doesn't even reach else {} before ending.

Comment: @Anthony I've updated my post, included the entire code. It should be working this time

Answer (score 1):

```
    previousChar = input[0];
    currentChar = input[1];
```

If an empty string was entered, there is no `input[0]` and there is no `input[1]`, so this becomes undefined behavior.

Your overall problem is checking, incorrectly, when the end of the string has been reached. The shown code attempts to extract a character at each position, place this character into a `std::string` of its own, and then compare it to an empty string.

This is not the right way to do that. This eventually results in undefined behavior, too, and a likely crash. `std::string`s have a `size()` method that give the number of characters in the string, so in your case:

```
input.size()
```

gives the number of characters in the string. Which can be 0. Then, you can iterate over each character of the string, and then implement your logic.

Answer (score 0):

From what I get by reading your code you are trying to print the number of duplicate characters. How I would go about doing this is as follows:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
 
  int num, characterCount;
 
  int main()
  {
    std::cout << "How many lines of input? \n";
    std::cin >> num;
     for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
    {
      characterCount=0;
      std::string input;
      std::cin >> input;
 
      for(auto iterator = input.begin();iterator!=input.end();++iterator)
      {
        if(iterator == input.end()-1)
          std::cout <<"Duplicates: " << characterCount
            << " " <<"Character: "<< *iterator << "\n";
        else
        {
          if(*iterator == *std::next(iterator,1))
            characterCount++;
          else
          {
            std::cout <<"Duplicates: " << characterCount
              << " " <<"Character: "<< *iterator << "\n";
            characterCount=0;
          }
        }
      }
 
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

First of all, you weren't using the `std` namespace. You need to use `std::` like I did below before every call from that particular namespace or you can just `using namespace std` at the top of the file after the include directives.

Second of all I ditched your algorithm using previous character and current character in favour of an approach using iterators.. A string is a standard c++ container from the standard template library so we can use iterators to go over it (or a standard for loop if you so desire).

The code prints duplicates for each character in the string, much as you wanted to do I think.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add using namespace std. In this program, I'm trying to count and print the number of different characters in a string, and then count how many of each character there are. I guess I should've made that clear.